# How to dumpdata from django-tenant-schemas?

Tags: python, django, django-models, dumpdata

I am trying to use manage.py dumpdata on my app's model but I am not able to see the json data in my dump file as I am using the django-tenant-schemas app to manage models for various clients. Is there any solution to dumpdata related to specific schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to do so:-

```
python manage.py tenant_command dumpdata --schema="schema-name" app_name.model_name --indent 4 > fixtures/dump.json
```

Or you can use:-

```
for t in $(./manage.py list_tenants | cut -f1);
do
    ./manage.py tenant_command dumpdata --schema=$t --indent=2 auth.user > ${t}_users.json;
done
```

I found the answer here:-

http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html?highlight=dumpdata